# css menu sub items not displatying in correct place

Tags: html, css

I am using the code below for a CSS menu but the sub items are not displaying below the parent items

```
    #CustomerMenu ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#CustomerMenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li a {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li a:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li ul li a { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #666;
}
#CustomerMenu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

how can i make the sub items display directly below the parent items.

i have created a JS Fiddle here to show full example i currently have

http://jsfiddle.net/h4joet22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h4joet22/1/

set `position:relative` of `li`

```
#CustomerMenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position:Relative;
}
```

**Edit**

setting `li` active

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/h4joet22/2/

Comment: is it possible to keep the parent item background color when hovering on a sub item?

Comment: sorted that by adding #CustomerMenu ul li:hover > a { ... }

Comment: also edited my answer with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4joet22/2/) @user2710234

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left:0;` from your CSS code at `#CustomerMenu ul li ul`  and that should align the submenu with the parent menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:relative` into,

```
#CustomerMenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

Add a class to the submenu:

```
<ul  class="subalign">
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=myaccount">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="/my-integra/?id=myaccount">My Account</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Your CSS:

```
.subalign li {
    margin-left: 54%;
}
```